# How to count only existing elements inside JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm working on this tool http://apps.evemilano.com/entities/ based on API.
This is the JSON file I get. Not every "itemListElement" has the same level of detail. I want to count all ItemList with a "description".

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
    "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult",
    "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
    "resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
    "kg": "http://g.co/kg"
  },
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/121gpq6x",
        "name": "Calogero Angelo Sacheli",
        "@type": [
          "Person",
          "Thing"
        ],
        "description": "Author"
      },
      "resultScore": 7.989742
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/m/0z3rcdq",
        "name": "Giovanni Sacheli",
        "@type": [
          "Thing",
          "Person"
        ],
        "url": "http://www.evemilano.com/"
      },
      "resultScore": 6.925036
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/m/07zy0l",
        "name": "Quarterback Princess",
        "@type": [
          "Movie",
          "Thing"
        ],
        "description": "1983 film",
        "detailedDescription": {
          "articleBody": "Quarterback Princess is a 1983 American made-for-television fact-based sports drama film by 20th Century Fox that chronicles the courage and determination of a teenage girl who struggles against sexism and fights to play on her high school football team. ",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarterback_Princess",
          "license": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Text_of_Creative_Commons_Attribution-ShareAlike_3.0_Unported_License"
        }
      },
      "resultScore": 0.945328
    }
  ]
}
```

Not every entities has one description, there are 3 entities and only 2 "description". How can i COUNT only existing "description" using PHP? I need to print "2" :)

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add more relevant tags to your question. You probably want a solution using a specific programming language: add it as a tag.

Comment: what language are you interested in? you might get different answers per programming language or library

Comment: sorry, PHP language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode your json payload with `json_decode`:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then you can iterate `$data['itemListElement']` and check if `$item['result']['description']` is defined:

```
$count = array_reduce($data['itemListElement'], function($count, $item) {
    return isset($item['result']['description']) ? ++$count : $count;
}, 0);

echo $count; // 2
```